# Is it possible to train an xgboost model in Python and deploy it Run it in C/C++?

Tags: xgboost

How much cross compatibility is there between the different language APIs?

For example, is it possible to train and save a model in Python and run it in C/C++ or any other language?

I would try this myself however my skills in non-Python languages are very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider dumping your model in a text file using

```
model.get_booster().dump_model('xgb_model.txt', with_stats=True)
```

then, after some parsing, you can easily reproduce the `.predict()` function in C/C++. For the rest I am not aware of native porting of xgboost to C

Answer (score 3):

You can dump the model into a text file as like this:

```
model.get_booster().dump_model('xgb_model.txt')
```

Then you should parse the text dump and reproduce the prediction function in C++.

I have implemented this in a little library that I call **FastForest**, if you want to save some time and want to make sure you use a fast implementation:

https://github.com/guitargeek/XGBoost-FastForest

The mission of the library is to be:

- **Easy**: deploying your xgboost model should be as painless as it can be
- **Fast**: thanks to efficient structure-of-array data structures for storing the trees, this library goes very easy on your CPU and memory (it is about 3 to 5 times faster than xgboost in prediction)
- **Safe**: the FastForest objects are immutable, and therefore they are an excellent choice in multithreading environments
- **Portable**: FastForest has no dependency other than the C++ standard library

Here is a little usage example, loading the model you have dumped before and assuming the model requires 5 features:

```
std::vector<std::string> features{"f0",  "f1",  "f2",  "f3",  "f4"};
FastForest fastForest("xgb_model.txt", features);

std::vector<float> input{0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8};
float output = fastForest(input.data());
```

When you create the FastForest you have to tell it in which order you intend to pass the features, because the text file does not store the order of the features.

Also note that the FastForest does not do the logistic transformation for you, so in order to reproduce `predict_proba()` you need to apply the logistic transformation:

```
float proba = 1./(1. + std::exp(-output));
```

Comment: seems the `proba` is numerically different from `predict_proba` in python? why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The `treelite` package([research paper](https://hyunsu-cho.io/treelite_sysml.html), [documentation](https://treelite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) enables compilation of tree-based models, including XGBoost, to optimized C code, making inference much faster than with native model libraries.